# Chatter feed tracking behavior with before trigger ( Order of execution)

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, chatter-feed-tracking, order-of-execution

Feed tracking shows field value as changed which are modified in before trigger,

Eg: A `before insert` trigger on `contact` , sets the `Last Name` to `new`

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert) {   
    trigger.new[0].lastname = 'new';

}
```

If I create a new contact with `Last Name` as `old`,
 feed tracking says user changed `Last Name` from `old` to `new`, Screenshot below:

---

[image]

---

Ideally there should be no updates in feed tracking, as the modification is done in a `before insert` 
Is this behavior expected? 
And there are no other `workflows` or `triggers` on this object.

Answer (score -1):

Your feed tracking are enable and this always works when you changes your record.
If you want to disable it follow the steps.

- Setup
- Customize
- Chatter
- Feed Tracking
- Contact
- Disable Name Checkbox
- Save

Hope it will help you!

Comment: The question is not about disabling tracking!!!